# Gmock with struct data

Tags: c++, struct, googlemock

I want to verify function parameters with gmock. Function parameters are in struct format as follows:

**SomeClass.h:**

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    SomeClass();
    virtual ~SomeClass();
    struct SomeData {
        int Value;
        int Serie;
    };
    virtual void getData(SomeData &data);
};
```

**SomeClass.cpp:**

```
#include "../include/SomeClass.h"

    SomeClass::SomeClass(){}
    SomeClass::~SomeClass(){}

    void SomeClass::getData(SomeData &data){
        data.Serie = 4;
        data.Value = 5;
    }
```

**MockSomeClass.h**

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "../include/SomeClass.h"

class MockSomeClass: public SomeClass {
public:
    MockSomeClass(){};
    virtual ~MockSomeClass(){};
    SomeData data;
    MOCK_METHOD1(getData, void(SomeData &data));
};
```

**testSomeClass:**

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

#include "../include/SomeClass.h"
#include "MockSomeClass.h"

using ::testing::_;
using ::testing::AtLeast;

TEST(testSomeMethod, test1){
    MockSomeClass mock1;
    SomeClass::SomeData data;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock1, getData(_)).Times(AtLeast(2));
    mock1.getData(data);
    mock1.getData(data);
}

TEST(testSomeMethod, test2){
    MockSomeClass mock2;
    SomeClass::SomeData data;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock2, getData(SomeClass::SomeData &data));
    mock2.getData(data);
}
```

When I run testSomeClass, test1 goes through without errors but test2 is causing trouble. Any proposals how to include data in struct format to function call with gmock?

Comment: What do you mean by `test2 is causing trouble`?

Comment: This is the error message: /testSomeClass.cpp:28:49: error: expected primary-expression before ‘&’ token
  EXPECT_CALL(mock2, getData(SomeClass::SomeData &data));
                                                 ^
/build/test/gtest/src/gtest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h:1846:20: note: in definition of macro ‘GMOCK_EXPECT_CALL_IMPL_’
     ((obj).gmock_##call).InternalExpectedAt(__FILE__, __LINE__, #obj, #call)
                    ^
/SomeClass/test/testSomeClass.cpp:28:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘EXPECT_CALL’
 EXPECT_CALL(mock2, getData(SomeClass::SomeData &data)

Comment: I am trying to solve this with a MATCHER, but I haven't succeeded so far. A simple example would be brilliant.

Comment: I had data.Serie and data.Value in wrong place (I just want to verify that getData -function is receiving parameters with certain values.) With this MATCHER it seems to work:                               MATCHER(data1AreEqual, ""){
 return arg.Value >= 5 && arg.Serie <= 4;
}

TEST(testSomeMethod, test2){
 MockSomeClass mock2;
 SomeClass::SomeData data;
 data.Serie = 4;
 data.Value = 5;
 EXPECT_CALL(mock2, getData(data1AreEqual()));
 mock2.getData(data);
}

Answer (score 1):

When writing googlemock expectation:

```
EXPECT_CALL(someMock, someMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...))...;
```

The only allowed arguments (arg1, arg2, arg3) are matchers - `::testing::Matcher<T1>` - where `T1` is someMethod parameter types. Fortunately `Matcher<T1>` value can be constructed from `T1` value.

So - this is not possible to use `SomeClass::SomeData &data` - because this is some argument declaration - not matcher value.

You probably wanted to use [`::testing::Ref`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#generic-comparison) matcher - like:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock2, getData(Ref(data)));
```